# How to get a list containing the most recent data from a series of products using Query function?

Tags: date, google-sheets

I have a list of products and its historical costs, and what I need is to generate a new list in which I get the most recent cost of each product.

For Example:

Product      Date         Cost
A     07/02/2023       10.50
A     08/05/2023       11.20
B     09/02/2023       30.10
B     10/02/2023       30.30

What I need to get:

Product      Date         Cost
A     08/05/2023       11.20
B     10/02/2023       30.30

I tried the following formula, which only brings the product associated to the most recent date, but not all of the products:

=query(H4:J8;"SELECT H,I,J WHERE I = date '"&TEXTO(MAX(I4:I);"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'")

What I get is:

Product      Date          Cost
B         10/02/2023      30.30

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GKaa8CEIsLVx0Er6DYhPpvcgumCXjyWx9Y2s3Ak_x8E/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach `(non-query based)`:*

```js
=sortn(sort(H5:J;2;);9^9;2;1;1)
```

`logic`: *uses [sortn](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) [display_ties_mode] = 2* ***Show at most the first n rows after removing duplicate rows.***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A `query`-based approach might be:

```
=query(H4:J;"select H,max(I),max(J) where H is not null group by H";1)
```

This is on the basis that the *max* date per group is the most recent date. If there are multiple entries for the same product on the same day, the use of `max(J)` means that the highest cost will be shown (although you could easily substitute with min/sum/avg as appropriate.